# C#: where is the bool method getting the value?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am not able to understand from where "EndsWithCheck" is getting the value and meaning of `myList.AddRange(new string[] { "jealous", "happy", "sad" });` In what format it is being added to `myList`? Is it in the form of a array or what?

```
 class Program
{
    private static bool EndsWithCheck(String word)
    {
        return word.ToLower().EndsWith("ous");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        myList.Add("adventurous");
        myList.Add("fabulous");
        myList.Add("happy");
        myList.AddRange(new string[] { "jealous", "happy", "sad" });
        myList.Insert(3, "melodious");

        Console.WriteLine(myList);
        Console.WriteLine(myList.Find(EndsWithCheck));
        Console.WriteLine(myList.FindLast(EndsWithCheck));
        Console.WriteLine(myList.FindIndex(EndsWithCheck));
        foreach (var item in myList.FindAll(EndsWithCheck))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add range method can be used to add any collection which implement IEnumerable interface (array in your case) and adds all elements of that collection to the end of the myList collection. After executing the AddRange method, your myList collection will have 6 string elements.
Your check method is just used to verify if the string ends with 'ous' suffix. It's a Predicate method which allow you filtering the collection with methods like Find(), you can also pass the lambda expression as well.

```
List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>)
```

Use this as a reference for other filtering methods you can use on List: http://www.csharp-examples.net/list/
Also the official documentation would be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Endswith method has a formal paramter i.e string word. From where is it getting that value?

Comment: It's a Predicate, so think about it as a lambda expression. For example your Find() method can rewrite as: miList.Find(word => word.ToLower().EndsWith("ous")). Your myList list implements IEnumerable interface and the Find() method simply iterate over your collection and use value of each element as parameter.